# Flot pie chart, distance between slices?

Tags: jquery, flot

With Flot, is it possible to modify the width/spacing between the slices of a pie chart? Currently the slices on my pie chart are too close together when they are small, its almost impossible to see them. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like a "broken-out" pie chart?  (Where the slices are exploded out of the original pie...)

Comment: Yeah, so that they are all exploded. Something like this I guess: http://www.advsofteng.com/images/explodedpie_p.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you limited to using Flot for this particular type of chart?  Flot is a great library... but, I haven't been able to track down an option to explode the pie chart.

At any rate, the possibilities that Flot offers for pie charts at present [can be found here](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/pie.html) in the SVN trunk of the Flot project.  There are a lot of variations on labeling pie charts... but none to actually explode the pie chart out.

A formatting option that you might want to try with Flot, however, (that might help readability for your chart in this case,) could be the `radius` option.  When you set the `radius` to a large value, it zooms in on the chart... like in Graph8 on [this page](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/pie.html):

```
$.plot($("#graph8"), data, 
{
    series: {
        pie: { 
            show: true,
            radius:300,
            /* more code here... */
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't explode the chart... but it might make it a little easier to read, at least.

If you aren't limited to Flot in this case... there is another (though, not as feature-rich,) chart library out there called [AwesomeChartJS](http://cyberpython.github.com/AwesomeChartJS/) that offers the option to explode pie charts (example found on "Demo" page of [that website](http://cyberpython.github.com/AwesomeChartJS/).)  But it might not have all the functionality (that Flot additionally provides,) that you may need.